# getSystemServices is undefined when called in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sensors

I want `TextViews` to display the sensors readings in a `Fragment`. When trying to initialize the `SensorManager` the `getSystemServices` is undefined in the `Fragment`, eclipse says.Why and how to fix it.

**Fragment**

```
public class FragSensors extends Fragment {

private TextView accXTv, accYTv, accZTv;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_sensors, container, false);
    accXTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.accXValue);
    accYTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.accYValue);
    accZTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.accZValue);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

}

private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Just one more method call:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

**Why that one extra method call?**
the `getSystemService()` method that provides access to system services comes from `Context`. An `Activity` extends `Context`, a `Fragment` does not. Hence, you first need to get a reference to the `Activity` in which the `Fragment` is contained and then magically retrieve the system service you want.

Comment: `getActivity()` can return null if it's not attached in the moment. Although it's extremely rare condition it can happen.

Comment: This directed me to `connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`, in a near ambit. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

Use:

```
getActivity().getSystemService(name)
```

Answer (score 6):

On Kotlin use:

```
this.sensorManager = activity!!.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NAMEOF_SERVICE);
```

Fragments cannot directly call System Services , You have to use Activity with which these Fragment is Attached

Answer (score 4):

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) 
requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this helped:

```
val manager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the context from the LayoutInflater.

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getLayoutInflater().getContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin this is what worked for me.

```
private fun hideKeyboard() {
        val inputManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        if (inputManager.isAcceptingText) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity?.currentFocus?.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
```