# Android getSystemServices is undefined in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-maps

I'm trying to use geolocation in fragments and getting error while initialization  (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE).

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (mapFragment != null) {
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(callback);

        location = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 12);
            return;
        }

        location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {


                String title = "";
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                try {
                    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                    List<Address> address = geo.getFromLocation(lat, longitude, 1);
                    title = address.get(0).getCountryName() + " , " + address.get(0).getLocality();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                LatLng mylocaion = new LatLng(lat, longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylocaion).title(title));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocaion, 10.2f));


            }
        });


        location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {


                String title = "";
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();


                try {
                    Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getActivity());
                    List<Address> address = geo.getFromLocation(lat, longitude, 1);
// I'm trying to use geolocation in fragments and getting error while initialization  (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE). 
                    title = address.get(0).getCountryName() + " , " + address.get(0).getLocality();



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                LatLng mylocaion = new LatLng(lat, longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylocaion).title(title));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocaion, 10.2f));


            }
        });

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use  getContext() or  getActivity() before that. You will need a context in fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use getContext() or getActivity() before that. You will need a context in fragment.

Look at this one too. [getSystemServices is undefined when called in a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427414/getsystemservices-is-undefined-when-called-in-a-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `getSystemService()` with `requireContext().getSystemService()`